# Can not find DbDataController

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Maybe it's a dumb question because of nobody seems to be the same problem, but i can not find DbDataController type.

I watched a presentation of Steven Sanderson (shown at the link below) and wand to comprehend the example given. Unfortunately i can not find DbDataController not even System.Web.Http.Data namespace. Have i to install something special?

I use VS2012 with EF5 Pre. I tried already to change target framework to .NET 4, drop EF5 package from solution and install EF 4.3.1 via nuget.

Any ideas?

Link: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in System.Web.Http.Data.EntityFramework.dll, which is part of the Nuget package "AspNetWebApi.Data" (version 4.0.20221.15125).

But it should be part of the [sample code](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/03/06/single-page-application-packages-and-samples/) accompanying Sanderson's talk.

Comment: After installation of 'Install-Package AspNetWebApi' DbDataController was still unknown. But under the given link Sanderson says to make sure install another nuget package (Install-Package SinglePageApplication.CSharp).

Now DbDataController is a known type. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: I think you need to run the command 'Install-Package AspNetWebApi.Data' from the Package Manager Console